# Using Gboard's phone layout on a tablet (or vice versa)

Tags: gboard

I use Gboard on a phone and a tablet. My preferred language is Maltese. With exactly the same settings, I get two different layouts. In particular, there's a missing button on the tablet that comes very handy when typing Maltese.

Here's the difference between the two layouts:

[image: phone missing the '-'/'~' key from tablet layout]

How to get the same keyboard layout on the tablet as on the phone?

Comment: Have you checked that both devices use the same version and the settings regarding language and layout are the same? https://support.google.com/gboard/answer/6380730?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en